# 'in between' or 'between'

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentences.

> 1. What is the name of the song **in between** 0:00 and 0:21 minutes?
> 2. What is the name of the song **between** 0:00 and 0:21 minutes?

I am not sure, which sentence is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Between* is a preposition, while *in between* acts as an adverbial ([from a fellow website answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-difference-between-in-between-and-between))

> *preposition*: I found myself caught between a rock and a hard place.
>
> *adverb*: There was a rock and a hard place, and there I was lying in between.